# How to change Google Play country without adding payment method

Tags: google-play-store

I live in European Union in country where some apps like Cortana and Google assistant are not avaiable. Now I am in Italy, and I will stay for few weeks if that is relevant,  so how can I change my country without adding payment method. I really do not whant to share some data with Google.

So, I deleted cache and data of Google Play and Play Services. And now I am unable to install any app in Play store, because  Google is forcing me to add payment method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change your region without adding a payment method from that region.

However, you can simply create a new google account and pick the region you like.

Additionally, if you added a payment method to the same account, you would lose any balance currency you might have in your account. It also takes a few business days to switch completely.

I currently live in the EU on a student visa and I had a similar problem. So I also resorted to making a new account because I frequently need apps from both locales.

Answer (score 3):

**Source:** [Change your Google Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en)

Unfortunately, you **cannot**. 
Relevant extracts

> To change your country, you need to set up a new country in Google Play. To set up a new country, you must be in that country and have a **payment method from the new country**.

(Emphasis added)

Now, you have two problems :

1. By clearing cache and data, you have ensured that you change your country (as explained in the source)
2. Your stay in Italy is only for few weeks.

   > You can only change your Play country **once per year**. So if you change your country, you won’t be able to change it back for 1 year

To sum it up, you have lost your old country information, you have to set 
up new country information and if you do that you can revert to your old country after one year

There is no way out from this awkward situation AFAIK... I feel sorry

Comment: Completely ridiculous what Google is doing here... Tip: Use a VPN to at least pretend to be in the country you need.