# How to mislead Play Store location other than using VPN

Tags: applications, google-play-store, geolocation

I want to deceive some apps like google play, or other apps in general, to make them think that my location is somewhere else and not in my country.

The reason I'm doing this is because, suppose there's a game launched or an update that is just available in a country X, but it's not launched yet or even not available in my country, I can access the app or feature by using something without really going to the country X. So far, the suggestion I found is using VPN, but that doesn't work. How to do this?

Comment: VPN for the purpose of spoofing location is a  poor tool because [1](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/249559/99059) and [billing address is used to determine your Play Store accessibility](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44733/131553) // If your device is rooted, you can spoof your location more effectively but that is also unlikely to help you (second link)

Comment: [Related somewhat](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220047/131553)

Comment: [This answer to use alternative app stores](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216831/44325) from the duplicate is very relevant.